# Create the links using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I have a implemented boostrap 4 navbar, and have a function that creates links.
It works and is there any efficient method to do in javascript.
I have three function that creates link for each hyperlinks .
Is it possible to do using cookie or any other efficient method using javascript

```
<script>
  function setAboutLink(lang){
    var url = lang+"/aboutus";  // will be xyz.com/en/aboutus
    window.location.href= url; 
  }
  function setContactLink(lang){
    var url = lang+"/contact"; // will be xyz.com/en/contact
    window.location.href= url;
  }
  function setListLink(lang){
    var url = lang+"/list"; // will be xyz.com/en/list
    window.location.href= url;
  }

</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top pb-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"+selectedLanguageName><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logoC mr-4"
            style="max-width: 100px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="setAboutLink(window.location.href)"
                   >About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="setContactLink(window.location.href)"
                    >Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="setListLink(window.location.href)"
                   >List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for this.

Comment: You could simplify your code by setting a global `lang` variable `const lang = window.location.href;` and have 1 method generating the link such as `function setLink(page) { var url = lang+page; window.location.href = url; }`, and call it from your DOM like `setLink('/contact')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why cookie comes into the picture, you just need to need efficient method here, You can write a generic function for that, In the whole entire website you may use it.

```js
function redirection(slang){
   window.location.href = window.location.href + '/' + slang
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top pb-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"+selectedLanguageName><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logoC mr-4"
            style="max-width: 100px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="JavaScript:Void(0)" onclick="redirection('aboutus')" >About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="JavaScript:Void(0)" onclick="redirection('contact')"
                    >Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="JavaScript:Void(0)" onclick="redirection('list')"
                   >List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var lang = 'en'; // default is en
  if (localStorage.getItem('lang') === null){
    localStorage.setItem('lang', 'ch'); // tou can have any condition for lang and set it here
  } else {
    localStorage.getItem('lang')
  }

  function setLink(path){
    // if lang var is there in localStorage lang var is ch otherwise en
    var url = window.location.origin + '/' + lang + '/' + path
    window.location.href= url;
  }

</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top pb-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"+selectedLanguageName><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logoC mr-4"
            style="max-width: 100px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="setAboutLink('aboutus')"
                   >About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="setLink('contactus')"
                    >Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="setLink('list')"
                   >List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</nav>
```

I write localStorage in first of your script. If localStorage lang var not exist, you set localStorage lang var with `ch`, otherwise for first time you set it for user in localStorage.
If localStorage not exist, default lang is en.